# Pde book suggestion.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am studying PDE. And I want to know introduction to PDE book's names, which contain direclet problem, Sturm liouville problems, cauchy problems, euler, eigen functions and like this. But the suggested book contains more examples with solutions. Please give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend *Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers* by Farlow. It's from an applied mathematics perspective as seen from the title, but there are a lot of worked out examples and covers a wide breadth of topics; the author really utilizes physical interpretations of PDEs to prepare you computationally. It's also very cheap (published by Dover books) which makes it a good alternative if you're not able/willing to dish out $80 for a textbook. In my opinion, I think it's very well organized and the examples are easy to follow - it only assumes a knowledge of ODEs.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. This book is one of the best AND at miniscule Dover prices!

Answer (score 7):

What is your background? Do you know any functional analysis? How is your measure theory? These are important things to consider when picking a book. Here are some books that helped me:

- An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations - Rogers and Renardy. This book assumes almost no background knowledge, yet treats all of the topics mentioned in your post and much more. Its also introduces quite a bit of functional analysis along the way. Also remarkable about the book is that no measure theory is needed. The book has many examples.
- Partial Differential Equations - Evans. This is the standard book in the field and the one that pretty much everyone learns from at the graduate level. While barely any functional analysis is assumed, your vector calculus and measure theory are assumed to be sound.
- Partial Differential Equations - Rauch. This is one of my favorite books and one of the first I learned PDE from. The approach of this book is somewhat different from the others. It spends a lot of time on the Fourier Transform and on tempered distributions and most methods in the book can be traced back to these. Measure theory and the "language of functional analysis" are assumed throughout.
- Partial Differential Equations - John. Even though I've only read one chapter from this book, I've heard many good things about the others too. Probably good to flip through and see if it suits your needs.
- Functional Analysis, Sobolev spaces and PDE - Brezis. This is a very good book if you already know some PDE and are looking to understand the concepts in a abstract functional-analytic setting. If you are just starting out, I would not recommend it.

Comment: I am undergraduate level. And I have taken pde course at first timeThank you so much. I look at each of the books you suggested

Comment: @user38355 why are functional analysis and measure theory important to learn PDE? I am student willing to learn PDE. Could you explain it more?

Answer (score 3):

The book [Partial Differential Equations: An intriduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470054565) by Strauss and the book [Partial Differential Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743) by Evans are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Were I you, I would use Schaum's outline for PDE. It's cheap, comprehensive and per your request it has plenty of worked out examples. Look it up.

Comment: Thanks I like schaum's outline for other all topics:)